# Auto send SMS through app when Network Signals are available

Tags: android

We are working on an Android app which sends required data through SMS.

We are able to send SMS through application, but the problem arises when the network is not available.
It shows SMS failed.

We are using Action_Send to send SMS when network signals are not available (want to avoid)
   - As it adds extra step of pressing send button of Internal SMS service (want to send it automatically)

Could you help to generate code which will send SMS like inbuilt SMS service i.e.

- SMS goes to outbox from where it waits and sends automatically when signals are available

Comment: Stack overflow is **NOT** a code generation site, it is a site to ask a question about something you are **ALREADY** trying to implement and part of it is not working. Read the FAQ.

Answer (score 1):

try this code to send sms

```
private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
{        
    Log.d("phoneNumber",phoneNumber);
    Log.d("MEssage",message);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(CONTEXT, 0,
        new Intent(CONTEXT,Object.class), 0);                
    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, pi, null);        
}
```

Comment: try this sms will go in outbox as sms failed

Answer (score 0):

When ever You don't have signal, Start a Broadcast Receivers to check Signal available. It will automatically broadcast a message to your application about the signel. Then start sending the message again.

```
public class SampleBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(intent.getAction() != null)
        {
            Toast.makeText(context, ""+intent.getAction(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            Log.d("onReceive","intent.getAction():::"+intent.getAction());

             if(intent.getAction().equals(android.net.ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION))
            {
                ServiceState _state = new ServiceState();

            }
        }

    }

}
```